# How to create a session when a user connects to Websocket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

When my PHP script launches, the user attempt to establish connection to a WebSocket. Once the first connection is established to the Websocket, I create the following session variables session.authorized. Then I update an object called `clients`. The `clients` object and each key represent a session is and each value is an object of every connection that is coming form the same session ID "same user."

```
object clients (
   session_id1 = object ('conn1','conn2','conn2'),
   session_id2 = object ('conn1','conn2')
)
```

After the user refreshes my PHP application, the script will try to connect again to the Websocket. At this point, I want to use the session data that I already stored for that users as the user have been already verified.

For my Websocket implementation, I am using socket.io on node.js. And I am using `express` framework and `express-session`.

**Problem**

When I attempt to read the session variables in my Websocket server, it does not seems to be saving as I am not able to retrieve the session data on the second request.

The problem with my code is that on the disconnect event the values `session_id` is always undefined. Also, when the user connect again the session variables do not exists "I can't re-suse it on the page refresh"

I think I am not creating the session or using it correctly.

**Question**

How can I save the session after a user is authenticated?
How can I know that the user is already authorized?

Here is my code

```
const env = require('./config');
const sess = require('./sessions');
const app = require('express')();
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const server = https.createServer(
    {
        key: fs.readFileSync('certs/key.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('certs/cert.pem')
    }, function (req, res){
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type');
    }
).listen(env.socket.port, env.socket.host, function () {

    console.log('\033[2J');
    console.log('Websocket is running at http://%s:%s', server.address().address, server.address().port);
});

const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const session = require('express-session');
const RedisStore = require("connect-redis")(session);
const cookie = require('cookie');
const sessionMiddleware = session({
    store: new RedisStore({
        host: env.redis.host,
        port: env.redis.port
    }),
    secret: env.session.secret,
    cookieName: env.session.name,
    rolling: true,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
         maxAge: env.session.duration
    }
});

io.use(function(socket, next) {
    sessionMiddleware(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
});

app.use(sessionMiddleware);
var clients = {};


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Welcome!');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    var origin = socket.request.headers.origin || '';
    var myIP = socket.request.socket.remoteAddress || '';
    var socketId = socket.id;
    var session_id = '';
    var authorized = false; 

    console.log(socket.request.session);

    if (!originIsAllowed(origin)) {
        // Make sure we only accept requests from an allowed origin
        request.reject();
        console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection from origin ' + origin + ' rejected.');
        return false;
    }

    if(socket.request.sessionID){
        session_id = socket.request.sessionID;
    }

    if(socket.request.session.authorized){
        authorized = socket.request.session.authorized;
    }

    socket.on('connectMe', function(msg){

        if(!msg || !msg.tokenId || msg.tokenId == 'undefined'){
            console.log('SessionId was not found!');
            return false;
        }

        if(!myIP){
            console.log('Could not find client\'s IP Address');
            return false;
        }

        var userCons = clients[session_id] || [];

        if(userCons.indexOf(socketId) == -1){
            userCons.push(socketId);
        }

        clients[session_id] = userCons;

        console.log(clients);

        var uncoded_token = new Buffer(msg.tokenId, 'base64');

        //autherize the user only once - until the session is terminated
        if( !authorized && sess.handleSession(uncoded_token, myIP, env.session.duration) ){
            authorized = true;
            session.authorized = authorized;
        }

    });

    socket.on('chat', function(msg){
        //only autherized users can chat
        if( session.authorized ){
            console.log('Chat Message: ' + msg);
            socket.emit('chat', { message: msg });
        }

    });


    socket.on('disconnect', function(msg){
        console.log('Closing sessionID: ' + session_id);
        var userCons = clients[session_id] || [];

        var index = userCons.indexOf(socketId);

        if(index > -1){
            userCons.splice(index, 1);
            console.log('Removed Disconnect Message: ' + msg);
        } else {
            console.log('Disconnect Message: ' + msg);
        }

    }); 

    socket.on('error', function(msg){
        console.log('Error Message: ' + msg);
    }); 

});


function originIsAllowed(origin) {
    // put logic here to detect whether the specified origin is allowed.
        var allowed = env.session.allowedOrigins || []

        if(allowed.indexOf(origin) >= 0){
            return true;
        }

    return false;
}
```